# Finding $f'(0)$ for $f(x) = x^{1/3} - x^{1/5}$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x) = x^{1/3} - x^{1/5}$, how would I go about finding $f'(0)$?

Would I have to appeal directly to the definition? I do not think I can use any derivative rules since the individual derivatives on the right side do not exist at zero.

Comment: You have been around for almost three years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: You said it yourself, the derivative doesn't exist. Differentiating yields $$f'(x)=\frac{5x^{\frac{2}{15}}-3}{15x^\frac{4}{15}}$$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout this only gives $f'(x)$ for $x\ne0.$ You cannot rely on it to prove that $f'(0)$ does not exist. ArtVandelay: yes, appeal directly to the definition.

Comment: @AnneBauval You are right.  I made an analytical error, which led to my making a comment that is not applicable.  I have deleted that comment.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments.  They were very helpful.   I was just trying to confirm if I had to use the definition directly.  I will be sure to read up on MathJax for next time.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the simplest way is to go back to the derivative definition. As $f$ is only defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$, we have:

$$ f'(0) = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}$$

As $f(0) = 0$, it yields:

$$
\begin{align}
f'(0) &= \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^\frac 1 3 - x^\frac 1 5}{x} = \lim_{x\to0^+}(x^{-\frac 2 3} - x^{-\frac 4 5})=\lim_{x\to0^+}(x^{-\frac 4 5}\times(x^\frac 2 {15} - 1))\\
&= \lim_{x\to0^+}-x^{-\frac 4 5} = -\infty
\end{align}$$

---

Above used the convention for $x^y$ to be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ if $y$ is an integer and only on $\mathbb{R}^+$ (aka $[0,+\infty)$ ) if $y$ is not integer. Another convention exists that also defines $x^y$ on $\mathbb{R}$ if $y$ is a rational $\frac n d$ and d is odd. It makes sense because $\begin{align} f: &\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\\&x \mapsto x^n \end{align}$ is a bijection when $s$ is an odd integer. We can then define $x^\frac 1 n$  on $\mathbb{R}$ as the reciprocal application, and $x^\frac p n$ as $(x^\frac 1 n)^p$. Above demonstration still stands by just changing $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$ with $\lim_{x \to 0}$.

I seldom use that second convention because it yields to weird things when you considere $x^y$ as a function of $y$. It is a nice continuous and even $C^\infty$ function if $x \ge 0$ but is only defined on $\{y \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists(p,q) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^*, y = \frac p {2 q + 1}\}$ when $x\lt0$. Worse, if we considere the series $u_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac 1 {3^i}$ it is convergent and its limit is $\frac 1 2$. So we get a sequence $x^{u_n}$ ($x \lt0$) that will have for limit $-\sqrt{-x}$. For example $(-4)^{u_n}$ converges to $-2$. Only one step before defining $(-4)^\frac  1 2$ to be $-2$...

Comment: Why is $f$ defined only on $x\geq 0$?

Comment: It is defined only on $[0,\infty)$, i.e $\mathbb{R}^+$ in Serge's notation. (Think about it: What is the cube root of $-1$?)

Comment: @nonuser: a non integer power is only defined for positive number. Think about $x^\frac 1 2 = \sqrt x$...

Comment: I don't see any problem like that if the power is ${1\over 3}$ or ${1\over 5}$

Comment: @jerkajerka & Serge: As nonuser said, many calculus books choose to define $x^{1/n} = \sqrt[n]{x}$ as the $n$-th real root of $x$ for all real numbers $x$ and odd integers $n$.  For example, *Calculus Early Transcendentals* (9th ed.) by Stewart et al. states on page 28 that "For $n = 3$ we have the cube root function $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ **whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$ (recall that every real number has a cube root)** [...] The graph of $y = \sqrt[n]{x}$ for $n$ odd ($n > 3$) is similar to that of $y = \sqrt[3]{x}$" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @L.F. A fair comment. My own first encounter with calculus was free of complex numbers, but apparently that is less common than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=x^{1/3}-x^{1/5}$ is differentiable at $0,$ then $f(2^5x)=2^{5/3}x^{1/3}-2x^{1/5}$ is differentiable at $0.$ Thus $$2f(x)-f(2x)=[2-2^{5/3}]\,x^{1/3} $$ is differentiable at $0,$ as well. But it is a common knowldege that the function $x^\alpha,$ for $0<\alpha<1,$ as well as its nonzero multiple, is not differentiable at $0,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As commented 1 hour ago: "yes, appeal directly to the definition". As $x\to0^+,$ since $x^\frac13=o(x^{\frac15}),$
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x\sim-x^{1/5-1}=-x^{-4/5}\to-\infty$$
hence $f'(0)$ does not exist.